# postgres data syncing with multiple server in a same table

Tags: postgresql

I have multiple servers LIKE `A,B,C`

Each server has its own user

```
A -> User-1 

B -> User-2

C -> User-3
```

I have a transaction table with two fields `user , transactionId` in every server

ex:  Server `A` has a table like this

```
    +-------+--------+
    |  user |trans_id|
    +-------+--------+
    |User-1 |      1 |   
    |User-1 |      2 |
    +-------+--------+
```

Server `B` has the table like this

```
    +-------+--------+
    |  user |trans_id|
    +-------+--------+
    |User-2 |      1 |   
    |User-2 |      2 |
    +-------+--------+
```

Server `C` has the table like this

```
    +-------+--------+
    |  user |trans_id|
    +-------+--------+
    |User-3 |      1 |   
    |User-3 |      2 |
    +-------+--------+
```

I need all the servers[A,B,C] should have the below data in certain time interval.

```
    +-------+--------+
    |  user |trans_id|
    +-------+--------+
    |User-1 |      1 |   
    |User-1 |      2 |
    |User-2 |      1 |   
    |User-2 |      2 |
    |User-3 |      1 |   
    |User-3 |      2 |
    +-------+--------+
```

How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with Postgresql logical replication. I think you might even be able to set it up so that all servers sync directly to the same table, or so that they sync to their own respective tables and then you use either triggers or a scheduled job to update your union-table.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html